# How would one seamlessly unwrap this shape?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am relatively new to Blender, and I have appeared to run into a problem.

Below me, I have a somewhat odd-shaped object I am trying to unwrap in such a way the texture properly connects to each face in a seamless manner.
The object in question:
[image]

I am using a 1024 x 1024 seamless image texture.
The texture used:
[image]

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you won't have a texture without seam with this kind of object, because you need to create some seams and they will interrupt the texture:

[image]

[image]

That said you can use a copy of your texture as *Draw* brush (in *Stencil* mode) in order to mask these seams:

[image]

Comment: You bloody legend! This really helped me, thank you! I have achieved the result I was looking for.  :)